# Yum : searching for a package with binary name

Tags: rpm, yum

Is there a way to search a package using the binary name.

for example I want to find rpm package for command "`ls`" then it should be `coreutils-6.9-10.4.i586` for example.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The yum command "whatprovides" accepts wildcards.  If you're searching for the package that provides as certain file or executable and do not know its full path, use "yum whatprovides */filename".

```
$ yum whatprovides */ls

coreutils-5.97-23.el5_4.2.x86_64 : The GNU core utilities: a set of tools
                                 : commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Filename    : /bin/ls
```

Answer (score 4):

```
yum provides /bin/ls
repoquery -f /bin/ls
```

...will both dtrt. Also recent versions of "yum" will automatically do a number of file lookups if you do:

```
yum provides ls
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, `scout bin ls` does that. This tool can index various type of repos (not only rpm, but java, etc) and find out what you need to install to get the required binary/command/javaclass/feature. It is well integrated with suse.

You can read more on scout [here](http://old-en.opensuse.org/Scout).

Comment: _Here_ is the solution. Don't forget: we are search for _not_ _yet_ _installed_ binaries! So, every other answer got a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use `dnf whatprovides $(which <prog>)` in a one-liner, where  is the binary / script / whatever you want to look up.

Answer (score -1):

The 'rpm -qf' command should tell you which package owns any installed file.

```
> whereis ls
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1p/ls.1p.g

> rpm -qf /bin/ls
coreutils-5.97-23.el5_6.4
```

Comment: suppose I dont have the package installed ... how can I get the package name knowing only the binary name ?